# Displaying rows and columns vertically

Tags: qt, view, model

I'm working on a qt application using the model / view architecture, and I'm having trouble displaying the columns from my SQLite table. I have tried to use a qlistview and a qtableview in many different ways, but have failed so far.
I want to lay everything out vertically like this:

| ItemView |
| --- |
| Data of row 1, column 1 |
| Data of row 1, column 2 |
| Data of row 2, column 1 |
| Data of row 2, column 2 |
| Data of row 3, column 1 |
| Data of row 3, column 2 |

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This does not work out-of-the-box. You either have to create your own model instead using a default QSqlQueryModel or try to create an own proxy model derived from QAbstractProxyModel. I would use the former.

Comment: Please show your code (preferably a [mcve]) and include an image of what you actually see.

Comment: @chehrlic Thank you very much! I created a class that inherits from QSqlTableModel and was able to achieve what I wanted